# Getting avalaible storage space

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to know what is the available Storage space? I can't find anything in Storage class.
I'd like to advise the user that a download couldn't be done if there is not enough space.

Maybe I can catch an exception (is it the, too much generic, IOException?) if there is no space left when downloading the file? Is there a way to be sure that this a storage space problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available in `Storage` but it is available in [FileSystemStorage.getRootAvailableSpace](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html#getRootAvailableSpace-java.lang.String-) which isn't quite the same but for most devices should give you the same answer.

Comment: It sould be fine but on simulator it returns always -1 and same on my Android phone. Is there another solution?

Comment: Looking at the code it seems this was never implemented for smartphones. Only for RIM & older devices. It should probably be fixed. I filed an issue here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1666